# How does barclays uk validate a user from a phone call

Tags: android, security, phone-number, phone-call

So basically on barlcays uk app you can have a button to direct call them from within the app.

The phone number is just a normal number +44 333.... doesn't seem to include any personal information or token about me/app.

So from the app it makes a call to this number +44 333... and I don't need to provide any information about me.

But if I call again the same number without the app I need to answer security questions.

So how do they do it? based on my current number and a small time interval?